# Login with Google throwing invalid_grant

Tags: php, google-api

Login with Google using Google+ API is not working in the server, but working correctly in the localhost.

it is not redirecting to domains.php file after authentication. getting the below like URL in the browser bar.

```
site.com/domains/domains.php?code=4%2FsrQHdwzRfgdf4isoIuxgfddgRvhgfdfg0WbQ6eV5gfyj7I8ER
```

> Error: Fatal error: Uncaught Google_AuthException: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant' in /home/myjobs/public_html/domain/login_with_google/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php

Anybody tell me the solution.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
//Include GP config file && User class
include_once 'gpConfig.php';
include_once 'User.php';

if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
    //Get user profile data from google
    $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();

    //Initialize User class
    $user = new User();

    //Insert or update user data to the database
    $gpUserData = array(
        'oauth_provider'=> 'google',
        'oauth_uid'     => $gpUserProfile['id'],
        'first_name'    => $gpUserProfile['given_name'],
        'last_name'     => $gpUserProfile['family_name'],
        'email'         => $gpUserProfile['email'],
        'picture'       => $gpUserProfile['picture'],
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($gpUserData);

    //Storing user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

    //Render facebook profile data
    // if(!empty($userData)){
    //     $output = '<h1>Google+ Profile Details </h1>';
    //     $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['picture'].'" width="300" height="220">';
    //     $output .= '<br/>Google ID : ' . $userData['oauth_uid'];
    //     $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
    //     $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
    //     $output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Google';
    //     $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="logout.php">Google</a>'; 
    // }else{
    //     $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    // }
} else {
    $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    $output = '<a href="'.filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL).'"><img src="images/glogin.png" alt=""/></a>';
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Google_IOException: HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to accounts.google.com port 443: No route to host in /home/sites/public_html/domains/login_with_google/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php:128

Comment: I don't know why many of them downvoting without telling the reason. since I am a learner I want to know the reason. Many of them also facing the same issue: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1527

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you why its only not working on the server. It should be failing every time you try to get a new access token. You are sending an access token to getAccesstoken() you should be sending a refresh token

## refreshing access token.

```
function getOauth2Client() {
try {

    $client = buildClient();

    // Set the refresh token on the client. 
    if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
        $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
    }

    // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
    // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

        // Set the access token on the client.
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 

        // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
        }           
        return $client; 
    } else {
        // We do not have access request access.
        header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

## create client

```
$client = buildClient();
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
// Add access token and refresh token to seession.
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
//Redirect back to main script
$redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

Sample code here [Google-APIs-PHP-Samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20People%20API/v1)